# Magento 2: Create multi store view site in nginx

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, language

I am recently struggling creating multi store site for M2.
My problem is that i need to create a website with this structure:

```
store1.website.com/us/ <- Main website 1 default
store1.website.com/de/ <- Main website 1 store view
store1.website.com/es/ <- Main website 1 store view
store2.website.com/us/ <- Main website 2 default
store2.website.com/de/ <- Main website 2 store view
store2.website.com/es/ <- Main website 2 store view
```

Tried using store code feature in M2 but it must have a unique code. What features are there to create this kind of structure in M2?

Comment: Try the suggestions [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html).

Comment: you also have to use proper rewrites

Comment: and use `$uri` in map settings